# Chrome Extension: Manipulate file in our extension directory

Tags: google-chrome-extension, filesystems

As the title says, is it possible to manipulate (e.g. Create, write, delete image) file from/to the extension folder?

Comment: It's possible but it won't help you because Chrome verifies the existing files of your extension and forbids modifications. If you want to create a new file, it'll probably live peacefully until the next update of the extension but again that's not really useful because there are more convenient ways to store data.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do it? Like storing user file to be used with my extension? I want the users to be able to modify their own image.

Comment: One of the usual methods is to read the image file `<input>` as a data URI and save it in any storage like a string. Another method is to use the Chrome-only HTML5 FileSystem API. Look for examples, should be easy to find, I think.

Comment: That Chrome HTML5 FS API sounds interesting. And if I want to use the first method, where do I store the string (without server because I want this extension can fully works offline)? Thank you for your time and sorry if I ask too much.

Comment: Like I said, you can use any storage e.g. IndexedDB or localStorage or chrome.storage.local.

Comment: Ohh right. Once again thank you very much sir it really helped me a lot!